# Using distribution of data instead of data in `EstimatedDistribution`

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data, distributions

Because of huge amount of data, the data saved in their frequency. for example `{1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,24}` saved as `{{1,11},{2,6},{3,1},{24,1}}` how can use this type of saved data in below command?

`EstimatedDistribution[data,PowerDistribution[a,b],ParameterEstimator->"MaximumLikelihood"]`

or

`EstimatedDistribution[data,ZipfDistribution[a,b],ParameterEstimator->"MaximumLikelihood"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `WeightedData[]` for the purpose:

```
FindDistributionParameters[WeightedData @@ Transpose[{{1, 11}, {2, 6}, {3, 1}, {24, 1}}], 
                           PowerDistribution[a, b],
                           ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
   {a -> 0.041666666666666664, b -> 0.3657540721946402}
```

Comment: P.S. Here is how to do the reduction automatically: `WeightedData @@ 
 Transpose[Tally[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 24}]]`.